# Should I use my GeForce GPU if I can run the game on Intel HD?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, cpu, gpu, gaming

If the game is an old game and runs with Intel HD graphics, is it a good idea to run the game using Intel HD. Or should I still run it on the GeForce card, since the GeForce card is made for running games?

Does it make a difference? In regards to heat, power usage, and CPU usage?

Answer (score 1):

It obviously make a huge difference in power usage even when idling and that's why the dual/hybrid graphics became so popular. There wouldn't be a point in having two graphics if they did pretty much the same job, would it?. And no, it's not the case of one being "made for games", it's the performance that differentiates them, regardless of the software type.

For any given software, if it runs fine with the integrated card then by all means use it. Use Nvidia only for software that requires it.